# Consuming Asp.Net webservices in android

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, asmx, ksoap

I have developed an android application that was previously developed in Asp.Net. Now my task is to communicate Asp.Net application and Android Application. I have to get data from dotNet application and display it in my android application also saves the android application data into database that was created for dotNet application. I have googled a lot for this but not find axact what I need. Kindly suggest any tutorial or guide me how to populate android application by getting data from asp.Net application and How to save android data into SQL server database of Asp.Net application. asp.net webservice is written I just need to call and dump data in .Net application

Thanks

Comment: Connect with your back-end server guy who made the .Net Web services he is the best guy who will tell you how the services are going to work, after that try these services in a rest client to check the response. Only after checking response you will be able to consume these .Net Web services.

Comment: He told me the working of webservices. How can I check the response?

Comment: Install RestClient add-on in Mozilla and ask your server guy to demonstrate the working of web services there.